# Search for only user specified text stored as flowdocument in sql table

Tags: sql, wpf, richtextbox, flowdocument

I am currently saving information from a rich text box as flowdocument to my sql table which has a column defined as nvarchar(MAX).
The data is stored as follows:

```
<FlowDocument PagePadding="5,0,5,0" AllowDrop="True" NumberSubstitution.CultureSource="User" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"><Paragraph>Messages at admin Level.Modified</Paragraph></FlowDocument>
```

The problem is when i search this column with a keyword "user", i want it to return records which has "user" in the paragraph and not in the Flowdocument definition.
How can i modify my search to reflect the user input text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where (col like '% user%' or col like '%user %") and col not like '%NumberSubstitution.CultureSource="User"'

Or

where CHARINDEX ( 'user', col , CHARINDEX('com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">', col) ) > 0